Where can I access spectra shift data on a given binary star?
I need to access spectra shift data which I can use to plot a radial velocity of a binary star vs time graph for an assignment.
I have looked at SDSS and I havent had any luck being able to access anything showing spectra shift vs time. What is the right tool to use for this?
